# Trying to add a queue to a Discord Music Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

After the Rhythm and Groovy discord bots were taken down, I decided to do some research on making my own music bot for our discord server. I found some code from a Youtuber tutorial(I honestly forgot the name and I feel so bad) and its able to Join, play, pause, resume and disconnect. But, I want to add a queue to it so my friends and I can queue some songs while playing some games. This is what I have so far

- main.py

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
    cogs[i].setup(client)


client.run('TOKEN')
```

- music.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
          await ctx.send("Get in a voice channel idiot!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        self.music_queue = []

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resumed ⏯️ ")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Im hoping to get a working queue, with a skip and clear command if possible. Thank you:)

Comment: Have you looked into the [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module?

Comment: You shouldn't really use the queue module in an async context, consider using [`asyncio.queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html?#asyncio.Queue) instead

Comment: @WasiMaster Do you know how I would implement that exactly? Like I said, im not huge into code yet. And im not sure what I should change in that example for it to link and work good with mine

Comment: @JordanAmo Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34) written by Mysty from the official discord.py server. don't just blatantly copy paste, look and try to understand. then do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

here is my queue command just get rid of the blacklist and it should work

```
async def check_queue(self, ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else: # display the current guilds queue
            commandd = "queue"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
                return await ctx.send("There are currently no songs in the queue.")

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Queue", description="", colour=discord.Color.green().dark_gold())
            i = 1
            for url in self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]:
                embed.description += f"{i}) {url}\n"

                i += 1

            embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using me!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

from the head dev of rage bots